# Group data into bins of 30 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a .csv file with some data. There is only one column of in this file, which includes timestamps. I need to organize that data into bins of 30 minutes. This is what my data looks like:

```
Timestamp
04/01/2019 11:03
05/01/2019 16:30
06/01/2019 13:19
08/01/2019 13:53
09/01/2019 13:43
```

So in this case, the last two data points would be grouped together in the bin that includes all the data from 13:30 to 14:00.

This is what I have already tried

```
df = pd.read_csv('book.csv')
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp)
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='Timestamp', 
freq='30min')).count().dropna()
```

I am getting around 7000 rows showing all hours for all days with the count next to them, like this:

```
2019-09-01 03:00:00   0
2019-09-01 03:30:00   0
2019-09-01 04:00:00   0
 ...
```

I want to create bins for only the hours that I have in my dataset. I want to see something like this:

```
Time         Count

11:00:00      1

13:00:00      1

13:30:00      2 (we have two data points in this interval)

16:30:00      1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you drop the rows with count = 0?

Comment: @JoeS I want to be able to group by hour, completely ignoring days. Even if I remove 0s, I get two rows for the interval 13:30, because the date is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`groupby.size`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) as:

```
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'])
df = df.Timestamp.dt.floor('30min').dt.time.to_frame()\
                 .groupby('Timestamp').size()\
                 .reset_index(name='Count')
```

Or as per suggestion by [`jpp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54309436/group-data-into-bins-of-30-minutes/54309637?noredirect=1#comment95439020_54309637):

```
df = df.Timestamp.dt.floor('30min').dt.time.value_counts().reset_index(name='Count')


print(df)
  Timestamp  Count
0  11:00:00      1
1  13:00:00      1
2  13:30:00      2
3  16:30:00      1
```

Comment: I get "AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Comment: equivalently `.dt.time.value_counts()..`

Comment: It works! What if I get a new data point, let's say at 13:54, how do I check which bin it belongs to?

Comment: @useruser123 as per 30minutes it belongs to 13:30 interval. That is why you have 2 values at 13:30, one 13:53 and other 13:43.